# Сортировка по сумме массивов в MongoDB

Tags: сортировка, mongodb, node.js

Подскажите, возможно ли сделать сортировку при запросе в монго по сумме массивов комментариев в коллекции?

В коллекции есть записи с комментариями, нужно отсортировать записи, где больше всего комментариев.

```
{
    "_id": "",
    "post": "",
    "comments": [
         {
             "_id": "",
             "text": "",
             "user": ""
         }
    ]
}

Content.find().sort('????').limit(20).skip(0).exec(function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Думаю, тут только через агрегацию можно решить. А не проще добавить поле `commentCount` и сортировать по нему?

Comment: Ну да, тоже вариант, так даже удобное будет.

Answer (score 1):

При использования метод [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate).

Первый этап в цепочке  — это [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) где нужно использовать оператор [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) который возврашает количество элементов в массиве.

Следующий этап  — этап сортировку используя оператор [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort).

```
Content.aggregate(
    [
        { "$project": { 
            "comments": 1, 
            "count": { "$size": "$comments" } 
        }}, 
        { "$sort": { "count": -1 } },
        { "$skip": 0 }, 
        { "$limit": 20 }
    ],  function(err, docs) {
            // callback();
        }
)
```

Если у вас много поля можно использовать в месте `"comments": 1` в `$project` этапе, `"comments": "$$ROOT"` где [`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT)  системная переменная которая 
представляет документ обрабатываемого в данный момент.